# Resize a Next.js Image component inside a div

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, nextjs-image

I try to make a section that contains on a side some text and on the other side an Image that should be responsive (i.e. that becomes smaller when the window's size is also becoming smaller).

Using a simple `<img src="/myimage.extension" alt="describe my image" />` does work perfectly. But as soon as I use the Next.JS Image component (in order to benefit from the optimization it does), it breaks the responsiveness.

Indeed, to make a kind of hero section with a responsive image I got this code (working perfectly fine):

```
<>
<div className={"h-screen py-0 py-20 text-center bg-blue-100 text-dark-blue"}>
  <div
    className={"flex flex-col items-center justify-center h-full md:flex-row app-container md:justify-between"}>
    <div>
      <h1 className={"text-red-400"}>With the Image component</h1>
      <p>It doesn't resize on the size of the viewport</p>
    </div>
    <div className={"relative"}>
      <svg
        className={"absolute right-0 z-50 hidden w-1/2 sm:block"}
        css={css`top: 25px;left: 25px;`}
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 674 674"
      >
        <circle id="Ellipse_8" cx="337" cy="337" r="337" fill="#e23b58"/>
      </svg>
      <img
        src={"/image.jpg"}
        alt={"Some image description"}
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</>
```

Then, replacing the `img` tag by an `Image` component breaks the responsiveness: the image never becomes smaller. It keeps its size.

```
<>
  <div className={"h-screen py-0 py-20 text-center bg-green-100 text-dark-blue"}>
    <div
      className={"flex flex-col items-center justify-center h-full md:flex-row app-container md:justify-between"}>
      <div>
        <h1 className={"text-red-400"}>With the Image component</h1>
        <p>It doesn't resize on the size of the viewport</p>
      </div>
      <div className={"relative"}>
        <svg
          className={"absolute right-0 z-50 hidden w-1/2 sm:block"}
          css={css`top: 25px;left: 25px;`}
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 674 674"
        >
          <circle id="Ellipse_8" cx="337" cy="337" r="337" fill="#e23b58"/>
        </svg>
        <Image
          src={"/image.jpg"}
          alt={"Some image description"}
          width={1103}
          height={628}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</>
```

You can see what's happening on this [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-clarke-3nrky?file=/pages/index.js). I'm looking for a way that enable me to control precisely how the Image component would be positioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not in the Image component. It's related to the styles applied to the div container.

If you remove items-center from the classes in lines 18-22 you will see that the image is resizing:

```
<div className={"flex flex-col items-center justify-center ...}>
```

Change to:

```
<div className={"flex flex-col justify-center ...}>
```

Comment: Yeah you're right. There is also an issue that appears then on the vertical align that can be handled using a higher flex container.